# Compute Engine accessing DataStore get Invalid Credentials (code: 401)

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am following the tutorial on 
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/
trying to use datastore from my Compute Engine project.

**Step 2** in the tutorial mentioned *I do not have to create new service account credentials when running from Compute Engine*.

I run the sample with:

```
node test.js abc-test-123
```

where abc-test-123 is my Project Id and that project have enabled all cloud API access including DataStore API.

After uploaded the code and executed the sample, I got the following error:

> Adams: { 'rpc error': { [Error: Invalid Credentials] code: 401,
>   errors: [ [Object] ] } }

**Update**:

I did a workaround by changing the default sample code to use the JWT credential way (with a generated .json key file) and things are working now.

**Update 2**:

This is the scope config when I run

```
gcloud compute instances describe abc-test-123
```

And the result:

```
serviceAccounts:
   scopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

According to the doc:

> You can set scopes only when you create a new instance, and cannot
>   change or expand the list of scopes for existing instances. For
>   simplicity, you can choose to enable full access to all Google Cloud
>   Platform APIs with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
>   scope.

I still welcome any answer about why the original code not work in my case~
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2):

This most likely means that when you created the instance, you didn't specify the right scopes (`datastore` and `userinfo-email` according to the tutorial). You can check that by executing the following command:

```
gcloud compute instances describe <instance>
```

Look for `serviceAccounts`/`scopes` in the output.

Comment: I think you are right. The value is "cloud-platform". This value seems not including "userinfo-email" scope. I will try test it later. Thanks

Comment: Yes, `cloud-platform` is a superset of `datastore`, but you still need to specify `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`, as mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/lookup.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 way to create an instance with right credential:

1. gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME --scopes datastore,userinfo-email
2. Using web: on Access & Setting Enable **User Info & Datastore**